# How to build flutter web app in debug mode?

Tags: flutter-web

`flutter build web` will build my flutter app with obfuscation and minification.

I want my error stack to be readable though.

How should I modify the command?

Comment: good question, did you find a solution?

Comment: nope. it seems it is impossible

Comment: maybe a good idea for a feature request on the flutter github

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try:

`flutter build web --profile --dart-define=Dart2jsOptimization=O0`

See:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/720dff6a94bd054e82ec4bf84b5cb802bbc52ddd/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/build_system/targets/web.dart#L238-L239

Comment: This isn't the same as debug mode tho. In debug mode (and `flutter run -d chrome`), `assert` expressions are executed. With this command, they aren't, and the obvious `flutter build web --debug` fails with 'Could not find an option named "debug"'

Comment: This was good enough for me to error trace production-only issues, where previously the minification was preventing me from seeing anything. However, it's not as good as debug mode for identifying the specific file causing problems.

Comment: I know this isn't the same as debug mode, but I think that it is currently the best you can get in build mode.

Comment: this solved my no minification problem for chrome web.   Is there a better way to remove minification because flutter build web --no-minify was not recognized.

Answer (score 13):

This is a old post, but I found the answer.

If you build the app with this line:

`flutter build web --profile --source-maps`

Then when you print a stacktrace, you'll get something like this:

```
Exception: Hello
at Object.wrapException (js_helper.dart:1123:37)
at _MyHomePageState__incrementCounter_closure.call$0 (main.dart:64:7)
at _MyHomePageState.setState$1 (framework.dart:1114:28)
at _MyHomePageState._incrementCounter$0 (main.dart:57:5)
at tear_off.<anonymous> (js_helper.dart:2099:9)
at _InkResponseState.handleTap$0 (framework.dart:909:26)
at tear_off.<anonymous> (js_helper.dart:2099:9)
at TapGestureRecognizer.invokeCallback$1$3$debugReport (recognizer.dart:253:16)
at TapGestureRecognizer.invokeCallback$2 (recognizer.dart:239:6)
at TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp$2$down$up (tap.dart:627:11)
```

If you use --source-maps with a release build, you will still get the dart file and line number, but the class/method names in the stacktrace will be obfuscated.

And, if you copy the `lib` directory into the root of built web directory, it will display the source code when you click on the dart file/line number in the stacktrace. Also, you can set breakpoints in the dart code, just like you can do when you do `flutter run web`.

Answer (score 8):

There's an issue on github for this feature, feel free to upvote ;)

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/96283

Answer (score 2):

The only way I have found to do this is to use `flutter run -d chrome`. We would then need to locate where the files on disk are located.

Comment: how can I find the location of the files?