# How Can I disable minify for flutter web release build

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, dart2js

How can I disable minification for a Web release build? It is messing up my JSON conversion and I don't want to rewrite all HTTP Layer.

My application works fine in debug & profile build for the web and works fine with release build for Android & iOS. Only web release build is having issues.

There is an option for dart2js compiler which can specify the level of minifying but I can't find any documentation on how to pass that option from flutter build.

Here you can see the option. https://dart.dev/tools/dart2js#basic-options

Comment: Why do you think minification is creating the issue?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore class names are different and my JSON conversion solution is relying on class names. all of my HTTP requests are crashing or returning null due to this. I tried printing the data type and it is weird.

Comment: Are you trying to use mirrors? What do you mean it's "relying on class names"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build flutter web app in debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59710360/how-to-build-flutter-web-app-in-debug-mode)